# RWD theme how to change related product orientation?

Tags: template, rwd, product-relations

Right now it is vertical, whats the best way to change the products to a horizontal view?

Answer (score 3):

The related products are rendered by the template `app/design/frontend/default/rwd/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`.  Just check the markup and the css for that template.
If you need a different markup your clone the file to your theme (that extends the rwd theme) and change it. You can also add any css file via the `local.xml` layout file in your theme in case you need css changes.

Comment: I was hoping there was a checkbox haha. Thanks